# What is a good way of rolling back a transaction in Postgres

Tags: amazon-redshift

I want to insert data into a table from a staging table but keep the data unchanged if an error happens.

What I have is a working happy path

```
            Begin transaction;
            DELETE FROM mytable;
            INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable_staging ;
            Commit transaction;
```

In case  the insert statement is failing how can I rollback the transaction?

Comment: Which one is it? Redshift or Postgres? But in general to rollback a transaction you use `rollback`

Comment: It is Amazon Redshift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PostgreSQL transactions will roll back on error automatically, see [this](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/postgresql/postgresql_transactions.htm).

> **Atomicity** − Ensures that all operations within the work unit are
>   completed successfully; otherwise, the transaction is aborted at the
>   point of failure and previous operations are rolled back to their
>   former state.
>
> **Consistency** − Ensures that the database properly changes states upon a
>   successfully committed transaction.
>
> **Isolation** − Enables transactions to operate independently of and
>   transparent to each other.
>
> **Durability** − Ensures that the result or effect of a committed
>   transaction persists in case of a system failure.

Comment: is this also same with redshift, which is a fork of Postgres?

Comment: @lollerskates "If any error is encountered while running a stored procedure, all changes made in the current transaction are rolled back. " https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/stored-procedure-transaction-management.html

Answer (score 0):

You can rollback a Postgres transaction using the [`ROLLBACK [WORK | TRANSACTION]`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-rollback.html) statement:

```
Begin transaction;
DELETE FROM mytable;
INSERT INTO mytable SELECT * FROM mytable_staging ;
Rollback transaction;
```

All the SQL commands are case-insensitive and the `transaction` part of the statement is optional, but I like to include it for clarity.